# Overwrite nginx.conf option keepalive_timeout in http{} keeping default nginx.conf file

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have an nginx HTTP server in which I want to have `keepalive_timeout  10s 10s;`.

I would just add it in a file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, however the default `nginx.conf` already contains `keepalive_timeout 65s;`, so if I simply do that, nginx complains because of defining that value twice.

So my workaround was to have a custom `nginx.conf` file where I removed that line, and then I could have my other file in `conf.d`.  But it would be simpler if I could solve it without having to change the default file, so I would only have to add things into `conf.d`.

Is it possible anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) you can define the `keepalive_timeout` in any of `http, server, location` directives, so you can add `keepalive_timeout  10s 10s;` to your specific `server` or `location` directive and it will override the default.